# Why isn't data being called from my REST api using an AngularJs factor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I built my REST api using the Django Rest Framework. Its functional and works nicely, however, when I try to call the data using an Angular factory, it doesn't work. I suspect I am missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.

In my api, the url

> /api/professor/

lists all the professor in my database and returns as JSON. So,

> /api/professor/(id)/

returns on particular professor.

Anyway, here's what I am doing, I have these 2 files in static/js/

**app.js**

```
var app;

app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.services',]);

app.controller('AppController', [
  '$scope', 'Professor', function($scope, Professor) {
    return $scope.professors = Professor.query();
  }
]);
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource']);

.factory('Professor', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/professors/:id', {
      id: '@id'
    });
  }
]);
```

My **index.html** looks like this

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- AngularJs -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/app.js" %}"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        {% verbatim %}
            <div ng-repeat="professor in professors">
                <h3>{{professor.name}} - {{professor.name_code}}</h3>
                <p>{{professor.university}} - {{professor.department}}</p>
            </div>
        {% endverbatim %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the browser, the code shows up, that is, {{professor.name}} and not the actual name of the professor. Any idea on how do to do this right?

Also, can anyone tell me what is the proper way to modularize angularJs files such as controllers and services. Thanks!

Comment: Open the console in your browser. You should then be able to see that the `service.js` is throwing a syntax error. Probably unexpected token at line 3. Fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, apart from the syntax error georgeawg pointed out, the problem was that the ngResource module was not installed.

Adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-resource.js"></script>` to my template fixed the problem.